# JavaScript Validator bind all buttons click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using this JS [validate plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) and it is working, but it will intercept all button clicks in the page and is trying to validate the form even I click `Back to Home`.

I only want the form to validate when I click the `login` button, when I click the `Back to Home` button I do not need to validate the form, just submit and redirect to the home page.

The reason I am still submitting the form on the `Back to Home` click event is because I need to capture the email address for use in my Controller.

How can I only capture the click events of the `Login` and `Back to Home` buttons?

Is it possible to stop the form from being validated when I click the `Back to Home` button?

HTML & JS Code:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
      <span class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="login">Login</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  data-action="backtohome" >Back To Home</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/js/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    if (action !== "nil")
    {
        $('#action').val(action);
        var form     = $("form");
        form.submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your binding the click events of any button with the class of `.btn`.

To avoid this you can bind the click events of only the buttons you need by adding an `id` to the `form-group` that contains your `login` and `back to home` buttons.

```
<div id='form-actions' class="form-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="login">Login</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  data-action="backtohome" >Back To Home</button>
</div>
```

Modify your jQuery to only capture the `#form-actions` button click events

```
$('#form-actions button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('action'),
        form = $("form");

    if (action == 'backtohome') {
        $('form').validator('destroy');
    } 

    if (action !== "nil") {
        $('#action').val(action);
    }

    form.submit();
});
```